# Create a full-width post every 4 post grids - Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I create a full-width post every 4 post grids? As in the following picture.

[image]

Here is my code wordpress loop.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-sm-6 grid-item '); ?>>

        <div class="entry-image">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('grid-thumb'); ?></a>
            <?php unbranded_entry_footer(); ?>
        </div>

        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php
            the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );

            if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php unbranded_posted_on(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <?php
            endif; ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php echo unbranded_string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 18); ?>&hellip;</p>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: you can check condition in for loop.

Comment: you can use modulus operator for this.

Comment: @shazyriver can you help how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

May I know are you using visual composer or creating custom template?
If using visual composer you can do it from back-end or place the condition to disable the sidebar from right using 
above the sidebar in page.php

```
<?php if(!is_page('your-page-slug' or ID)) { ?>

/*sidebar code*/

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm not using Visual Composer, this is index.php file with default post wordpress loop.

Comment: can you please share URL I can help you.

Comment: You can check here: http://mooncityblog.unbranded.id/ Thanks @Israr Mansuri

Comment: by removing all the widget from side bar you can do this but they will also remove from inner page.
for this you can create the custom template for it.

Comment: I will do it for you just send and email here israrmansuri92@gmail.com and no cost for this. :)